# How to save each array to each document with 'for' in Nodejs with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to save each array data into each document at Nodejs.
Therefore I made this code below.
But when I run this code, it only saves body[0].
Could you recommend some solution?

```
exports.saveOrder = (req, res) => {
       const body = JSON.parse(res);

        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i += 1) {
          const eachBody = body[i];

            const order = new Order(eachBody);

            order.save();

            return res.send('order is saved');
          }
        }      
  }
};
```

Comment: You should check body.length first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Db operations, You need to use promise or async/await, and send response once after all orders saved to DB. Add `try/catch` to catch errors as well.

Check this code, it should work now.

```
exports.saveOrder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
        const body = JSON.parse(res); // check this before do you realy need to parse it or not
        const allResults = []; 
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i += 1) {
          const eachBody = body[i];
          const order = new Order(eachBody);
          const result = await order.save();
          allResults.push(result);
        }
        return res.send(allResults);
   } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return res.send(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have send the response(used return) inside the for loop.
So it saves body[0] and return the response.

Use "return" outside the "for loop".

```
    for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i += 1) {
        const eachBody = body[i];
        const order = new Order(eachBody);

        order.save();

    }
    return res.send('order is saved');
```